# How to generate artificial sequential data for machine learning?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

Sklearn provide different data generation functions such as `make_blobs` and `make_regression` in `sklearn.datasets`.

However, I am not aware of any functions that can generate sequential data. Is there any existing libraries that can generate artificial sequential data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of series you want. Check out this repository for generating different kinds of simulated series. It's called [TimeSynth](https://github.com/TimeSynth/TimeSynth)

But if you just want something you can easily modify yourself, try writing a function similar to this:

```
def SynthSeries(start,end,stepSize,coefficients):
    import numpy as np
    samples = np.array(np.arange(start,end,stepSize))
    array = np.array(np.zeros(np.shape(samples)))

    for coeff in coefficients:
        array = np.add(array,(np.sin(coeff*samples)))
    return array, samples
```

This is sort of a reverse of a fourier transform, if you know the base frequencies of series you want to create, you can pass it into this function to recreate the signal. 
You can use it like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
(SeqData,samples) = SynthSeries(0,20,0.1,[12,3,1,22])
plt.plot(samples, SeqData)
plt.show()
```

[image]